# React props return as undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have a nav bar component I'm making in React and I am passing in a JSON object and a simple string as a prop:

```
<NavBar links={ navlinks } hello="hello" />;
```

However I try calling the props in my component and they do not work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './BasicNavBar.css'
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'


export class NavBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        hidden: false
      };
  }

 toggleNav = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      hidden: !this.state.hidden
    });
  };

  render(){
    console.log(this.props.links)
    return(
      <nav className="navbar">
      <span className="nav-bar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle" onClick={this.toggleNav} >
        <span className="nav-bar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
          <i className="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </span>
      </span>
        <a href="#" className="logo"></a>
        <ul id="main-nav" className={ this.state.hidden ? 'active' : 'hidden' }></ul>
      {
        Object.keys(this.props.links).map(key => {
          <li><a href="#" className="nav-links">{key}</a></li>
        })
      }
      </nav>
    )
  }
}
```

I've tried `this.props.hello` and `this.props.links` and they both come back undefined. I've also tried to returning `props` but it returns as an empty JSON string.

Comment: Do you actually get an error message?

Comment: `props.hello` not `this.props.hello`. Because you want to access the passed props.

Comment: Prove it :) make it a snippet, and show that it doesn't work. It is true however that your current console.log will throw an error as _this.props is not yet defined in the constructor

Comment: Your code works for me, I tried it in a codepen.   https://codepen.io/anuradha15/pen/BezNBB

Comment: I've tried both and still undefined and both still don't work. Is it cause I'm going through storybook to render them?

Comment: Added my full code cause copying and pasting still did render in codepen cause i hardcoded the first link.

Comment: @KyleCalica-St just wrote you an answer, let me know if that's helpful to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So very subtle thing I should've caught early!

```
  Object.keys(this.props.links).map(key => {
        <li><a href="#" className="nav-links">{ this.props.links[key] }</a></li>
   }
    );
```

The problem is I used the arrow function with `{}` rather than `()`.

`{}` means  statements therefore I have to use `return` rather than just have the statement there.

I have two ways of fixing it:

```
Object.keys(this.props.links).map(key => 
        <li><a href="#" className="nav-links">{ this.props.links[key] }</a></li>

    );
```

or

```
Object.keys(this.props.links).map(key => {
        return <li><a href="#" className="nav-links">{ this.props.links[key] }</a></li>;
   }
    );
```

I used `()` cause I only have one statement so it's cleaner.

Arrow functions from MSDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is first check that this.props.links is a truthy-value before doing your .map(). I bet there's some asynchronous logic happening here where we're trying to access your props before it gets passed down.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './BasicNavBar.css'
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'


export class NavBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        hidden: false
      };
  }

 toggleNav = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      hidden: !this.state.hidden
    });
  };

  render(){
    console.log(this.props.links)
    return(
      <nav className="navbar">
      <span className="nav-bar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle" onClick={this.toggleNav} >
        <span className="nav-bar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
          <i className="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </span>
      </span>
        <a href="#" className="logo"></a>
        <ul id="main-nav" className={ this.state.hidden ? 'active' : 'hidden' }></ul>
      {
         this.props.links ? (
             Object.keys(this.props.links).map(key => {
                return <li><a href="#" className="nav-links">{key}</a></li>
             }) 
         ) : (
            <div></div>
         )
      }
      </nav>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: While this has made the error go away, my props `<NavBar links={{'title': 'firstNav'}} hello="no" />` still won't populate.

Comment: Solved it! Though I wanted to let you know I did implement your code here due to better coding practices but it didn't solve my problem. Thank you though Christopher

Comment: I posted my answer. Easy to fix mistake on my part. But I left a full explanation for anyone else. Less React mistake and more JS arrow functions mistake.

Comment: @KyleCalica-St oh whatt I think I did have that in my solution ahah. Sorry I should have made that explicit, or I think I just thought you already were using return. :)